# “every class in java extends the MetaClass Object” does it imply that every subclass causes a Diamond issue

Tags: java, inheritance, fact

These two facts in java

Fact 1

“**Every class in java by default extends the java meta class `Object`**”

and

Fact 2

“**Multiple inheritance is not allowed in java**”  read more about diamond proble here  [Java inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801229/java-inheritance/5801248#5801248)

are quiet confusing

Suppose `ClassB` extends `ClassA`  then according to fact1 `ClassB` extends `Object`

[image]

Does that mean `ClassB` is extending both `ClassA` and `Object`? Is it a case of multiple inheritance?

If it’s not multiple inheritance then how aren't the two statements contradictory?

Comment: putting it as a QA knowledge share

Comment: Answer updated with example

Comment: In Fact 1, "by default" is key to the concept.

Answer (score 7):

> “Every class in java by default extends the java meta class Object”
>   //fact1

Every Class extends `Object` class, **only if they don't extend any other class directly**.

If a class `Test` extends another `Sample` class, then `Test` don't extends `Object` class directly, but, inheriting the Object class behaviors through super class `Sample`, which directly extends `Object` class.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for providing the source of your facts. Now I can go into a bit of detail.

**"Head First Java 2nd edition" says on page 208:**

> **Every class in Java extends Object**
>
> Class Object is the mother of all classes; it's the superclass of *everything*.

Further down in the paragraph it says:

> ***Every class you write extends Object,*** without you ever having to say it. [...]can think of it as though a class you write looks like this: `public class Dog`**`extends Object`**`{ }` [...] Dog *already* extends something, *Canine*. [...] The compiler will make *Canine* extend Object instead.

While the general idea that they're trying to communicate (that every class in Java has `java.lang.Object` as **a** superclass) is correct, they are using the wrong terminology, and the example using `Dog` is plain wrong and that is leading to your confusion.

I've written a Java compiler (for Java 1.4) and I'm pretty familiar with the Java Language Specification, so bear with me.

To prove that the terminology is "Head First Java" is wrong I need to quote from the Java Language Specification, which is a bit technical.

But to start with I can give you an easier explanation how you can see this.

**Better definition**

> **Every class in Java that does not `extend` another class explicitly, extends `Object`**
>
> When you write:
>
> ```
> class Canine { }
> ```
>
> Then the compiler takes this to mean:
>
> ```
> class Canine extends Object { }
> ```
>
> But when you write:
>
> ```
> class Dog extends Canine { }
> ```
>
> Then the compiler sees that you have already explicitly extended a class, and
>   doesn't change the meaning of your code.

Since Head First Java second edition is based on Java 5, I'll use the Java Language Specification for that version of Java.

The meaning of *extends* is defined in **[section 8.1.4 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.1.4)**:

> **8.1.4 Superclasses and Subclasses**
>
> The optional extends clause in a normal class declaration specifies
>   the *direct superclass* of the current class.
>
> ```
> Super:
>   extends ClassType
> ```

As you see, *extends* only refers to a *direct* superclass. In the example in Head First Java, Dog doesn't extend Object, because its direct superclass is *Canine*. Only *Canine* extends Object.

What they meant to say is that Object is a superclass of all other classes in Java. This is defined in **[JLS section 4.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html#4.3.2)**:

> **4.3.2 The Class Object**
>
> The class `Object` is a superclass (§8.1) of all other classes. A
>   variable of type `Object` can hold a reference to the `null` reference
>   or to any object, whether it is an instance of a class or an array
>   (§10). All class and array types inherit the methods of class
>   `Object`, [...]

I'm afraid that you got sidetracked by the misleading way that this was presented in the 2nd edition of Head First Java.
Hopefully that have already fixed this in newer editions (if anyone has one, please confirm/refute), otherwise we should inform the authors.

Comment: Please refer to Head  First Java 2nd edition, ( page no 208 ) .

Comment: It's written in bold "Every class in Java extends class Object" . And the line "The compiler will make Canine extend Object instead"

Comment: You quoted " Every class in Java hasObject as an ancestor, but it not correct to say that every class in Java extendsObject. " . please point me to any documentation or reference which may help me to understand it better.

Comment: @veer7 Thanks for providing the reference to the source of your facts. I've completely updated my answer and pointed out where Head First Java is wrong, and what is a better way to see this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both the statements are correct.

It’s true that every class in java extends the meta class `Object`.

Still ClassB doesn’t have multiple inheritance because at compile time java shifts the `Object` Class by one level.

[image]

This way now `ClassA` now extends `Object` and not `ClassB`.

This way `ClassB` is not having multiple inheritance so fact2 is followed.

Now `ClassB` extends `ClassA`  and `ClassA`  extends `Object` thus through **MultiLEVEL Inheritance** ClassB extends `Object`; fact1 followed